# Certain scripts failing when using subprocess.Popen() but run flawlessly in crontab or manual runs

Tags: python, cron, subprocess, debian

I have a `cron.py` script that is run under crontab on a Debian 10 server. This file effectively takes place of the crontab so that script runs can be updated via Git. `crontab` runs `cron.py`, `cron.py` runs Python scripts using [subprocess.Popen()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).

Most scripts run just fine using this system. However, two are failing to finish running. The start, run for a short interval (usually less than a minute), and then hang indefinitely. The two scripts:

- `reports.py` connects to Amazon MWS and downloads previously requested reports to a local directory.
- `inventory.py` parses several thousand local files and uploads their contents to Google Sheets.

These two processes are fully separate and do not access the same resources, except AWS Cloud Watch Logs for logging. They both run 1 hour apart.

Most of what I've tried is just investigation. I am not getting back any exceptions, none appear to be hit, the scripts just hard stop and are cleaned up after a 2-hour timeout. If I `strace` the locked process, it just shows the last logging call.

While troubleshooting this, I did build out CloudWatch metrics to track peak memory usage for each script. Many other scripts are using far more peak memory than others, so I don't believe this is memory-related. I switched from [subprocess.Popen()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to [psutil.Popen()](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Popen) to enable this.

If I run the scripts manually through SSH, or on my local Windows machine, they work perfectly. As an interim solution, these are being run through crontab a half-hour after their normal run time so that I can still get logs for the failures while having functioning processes.

The Popen call is as follows (lots of copy-paste and anonymizing):

```py
TIMEOUT = 60*60*2

processes = []
args = ['python', 'cron.d/scriptname.py']

use_shell = False
if os.name == 'nt':
    use_shell = True

po = psutil.Popen(
    args,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=use_shell,
    cwd=os.path.join(abspath, to, script),
    text=True,
    universal_newlines=True,
)
processes.append(po)

while len(processes) > 0:
    for proc in processes:
        if ((datetime.now()-start_time).total_seconds() > TIMEOUT):
            proc.kill()
            time.sleep(10)  # Wait for process to handle kill signal
        else:
            if proc.poll() is None:
                time.sleep(1)
                continue

        (stdoutdata, stderrdata) = proc.communicate()
        returncode = proc.returncode

        # Log process success/fail based on return code here

        processes.remove(proc)
```

I'm sure there will be some questions on this, as a lot is going on in `cron.py`, and I'm happy to provide more information!

EDIT: Added `use_shell` setup to code. This is used so Windows testing can be performed (environment and other resources not passed in Windows if `shell = False`).

Comment: BTW, a real programmer should give a better name then `cron.py`. Usually the problems are: different environment (cron set PATH and HOME to sensible values). Not using absolute paths (so it depends on when the PWD call is made). Adding the exception you get (the lines and the exception error should be enough). Note: it is also not clear where you installed crontab. As user or as systems (so run by root)?

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't meet your standards for a "real programmer".

Comment: The environment is the same. All paths are absolute. No exceptions are thrown, the subprocesses hard freeze and are caught and killed by the timeout. If an exception were thrown and the script failed, it would be caught in `sdterrdata` and in the scripts own try-except blocks. Crontab is installed as a user. Script names and much of this code is given with generic script and variable names, and the above code will not execute as written. This is intentional for the sake of confidentiality.

Comment: Also, the script runs perfectly if manually called by the user in terminal (python scriptname.py or python /absolute-path/scriptname.py), but launching as a subprocess through `subprocess.Popen()` or `psutil.Popen()` fails with a hard lock after a random interval of time. Scripts have run anywhere from 1 to 8 minutes before freezing with no given reason.

Comment: Sorry, it was a joke. Unfortunately I see many programmers (and worse teacher) that uses bad variable names. You know...when somebody else should fix codes. So it is just a bad habit (you describe "what it is", not the correct "what it does").

Comment: On your example, `python` and `cron.d/` are not absolute paths. The `PATH` variable is probably different. It is very difficult to find the error, but it is also a common problem, so you should debug: add sys.stderr.write() in different places, to see where the problems/differences are (cron should send you a email). Check (and print results of) `os.path.exists` and `os.stat`. Print every file/path you use, possibly plain and with `os.path.abspath`. Note: security policies could also affect permissions.

Comment: And the last common problem: many programs (and also python) tend to use different cache mechanism if the stdout is attached to a console or a file (pipes often are seen as files). if you have control of Popen process, set "line cache" or just use `sys.stdout.flush()` after every write. This force OS to send line through the pipe, so `Popen` receive and could read it.